# Format a number to show thousands and decimal separators

Tags: ios, objective-c, formatting

I am trying to make number like this 123456.567  to be like this 123,456.56 for USD and 123,456.567 for any another currency

My code is :

```
double fromAgainstJOD = amountVal * fromCurrency.SellRate;
double result = fromAgainstJOD / toCurrency.SellRate;

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];

NSString* formattedString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:result]];

if (toCurrency.SellRate == 0) {
    result = 0;
}
if ([toCurrency.Code isEqualToString:@"USD"]) {
    [resultLbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %0.2f", toCurrency.Code, result]];     
} else {
    [resultLbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %0.3f", toCurrency.Code, result]]; 
}
```

So i want to set in resultLbl the number with thousand sepator and decimal fraction for each currency code.
USD => 2 fraction
other currency => 3 fraction

Comment: For any currency don't use double. Use decimal type and it's proper format. Double format will cause money lost during the operations.

Comment: the double is working fine for me so the result in USD would be 7384.550 but what i need is to show it as 7,384.550
if i want to change to nsnumber i cant show it as 7,384.550 it shows as 7,384.55

Comment: Floating point numbers should never be used when dealing with money. Just because it works on your tests, doesn't mean it's always correct! See: blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/09/floating-point-and-currency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figure out how to do it

```
if ([toCurrency.Code isEqualToString:@"USD"]) {
    [formatter setFormatWidth:2];
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3;
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 3;
    formattedString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:result]];

    [resultLbl setText:formattedString];
}else
{
    [formatter setFormatWidth:3];
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2;
    formattedString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:result]];
    [resultLbl setText:formattedString];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fix.  in your formatter where you are checking your usd or other  if USD set the formatWidth to 2, otherwise set to 3

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];

NSString* formattedString;

if (toCurrency.SellRate == 0) {
    result = 0;
}
if ([toCurrency.Code isEqualToString:@"USD"]) {
    [formatter setFormatWidth:2];
    formattedString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:result]];
    [resultLbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %0.2f", toCurrency.Code, result]];     
}else
{
    [formatter setFormatWidth:3];
    formattedString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:result]];
    [resultLbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %0.3f", toCurrency.Code, result]]; 

}
```

**It looks like setFormat appears in the ios Documentation even though it does not work.**

Sample from:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter =[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *newAttrs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[numberFormatter setFormat:@"$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)"];
[newAttrs setObject:[NSColor redColor] forKey:@"NSColor"];
[numberFormatter setTextAttributesForNegativeValues:newAttrs];
[[textField cell] setFormatter:numberFormatter];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Conditionally setting the setFormatWidth solved the issue for me.  Strange that Apple's documentation used just the setFormat.  Sorry for the mistake.